# Get the column name of list

Tags: list, column

I tried this:

```
var fieldValues = currentItem.get_fieldValues();
```

But it returns [object object]. How can I see through this without know the column name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below script.

```
var fieldValues = currentItem.get_fieldValues();  

console.log(JSON.stringify(fieldValues));
```

Once script is executed second statement will print the data in console in readable format.

Comment: In browsers, including IE, you can just log the object to the console without having to stringify it. In fact this lets you expand/collapse nodes so it's easier to read.